# how to avoid 'style' and 'explode' OPEN API 3.0 keyword while marshalling the OPEN API 3.0 object

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I have a swagger 2.0 file where in parameters section it does not have **style** and **explode** keyword.

Steps :

1. I am unmarshalling swagger 2.0 file to OPEN API 3.0 object.

   in swagger 2.0 file  param section looks like below :

```
      {
        "name": "x-request-id",
        "in": "header",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Please enter a unique UUID value",
        "schema": {}
        
        }
```

2. After getting the OPEN API 3.0 object , i am marshalling it into OPEN API 3.0 file
3. There i could see extra keywords **style** and **explode** in the parameters section as shown below.

```
 {
          "name" : "x-request-id",
          "in" : "header",
          "description" : "Please enter a unique UUID value",
          "required" : true,
          "style" : "simple",
          "explode" : false,
          "schema" : { }
        }
```

4. These 2 extra keywords are not required.
5. How to remove this 2 keyword from parameters section in OPEN API 3.0 file

I am expecting the param section in OPEN API 3.0 marshalled file to not include **style** and **explode** keywords

Comment: are you using a specific generator? what are the steps you follow to reproduce the same scenario?